# How to remove this jsp error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="Update_job.jsp?ename=<%=ename%>"/>
```

Here i got error that says: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [=] is not a hexadecimal digit "

Is there any way to sort it out?

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace? And what is the value of `ename`?

Comment: here ename's value is the name of employee. Say it is, Shamol Kumar das.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this:

`<jsp:forward page="URL" > 
         <jsp:param name="ParamName1" value="ParamValue1" /> 
          <jsp:param name="ParamName2" value="ParamValue2" />
 </jsp:forward>`

also for more exploration go through this link http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/actions/forward

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you explore using the JSP Expression Language together with JSTL.

For example, ${temp} will result in a search for the variable, in this case temp, within the page, request, session and application scopes. Much nicer than using scriptlets and JSP expressions.

In this way you can eventually get rid of all the inline Java from your JSP.